# Angular html5mode disallows to go directly to an URL

Tags: angularjs, iis

in my Angular v1 app, I enabled the `html5mode`. I also fixed the '404 error' on the page refresh by applying the config taken from here https://coderwall.com/p/mycbiq/deep-linking-angularjs-on-windows-azure-iis

But there's another issue

I have 2 pages/routes

```
domain.com/signin
domain.com/reset
```

The `domain.com/signin` is the main page. On that page there is an anchor `<a>` by which I can go to `domain.com/reset`. But when I try to open `domain.com/reset` in the browser's address bar, I'm being redirected back to the `domain.com/signin` page. How to set the app/IIS config to allow me open `domain.com/reset` ?

states definition:

```
$stateProvider.state('common', {
        url: '/',
        data: { restricted : false },
        views: {
            "main": {
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html'
            },
        }
     })
     .state("login",  { 
            parent: 'common',
            url: 'signin',
            controller: 'loginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html'
    })
    .state("passwordResetStep1",  { 
        parent: 'common',
        url: 'reset/:id',
        controller: 'loginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html'
    })
```

Comment: you should provide code of both your router and the anchor.

Comment: At least you should tell what is returned by server when http get 'domain.com/reset'

Comment: server returns 200 OK status. I also notice the same behavious when I turned off the html5mode